# Red light in the depths of the ocean

Tags: optics

I've read that fish in the deep ocean tend to be red because it makes them look black for other fish, thus reducing their chance of being eaten.
Why do they look black?

Comment: Where did you read this? Unless you can provide something to go on, this question is very vague.

Comment: I have put an answer because I think there is physics in it, but I think the down votes reflect the fact that it could be seen as biology and, no offence, it's something you could research yourself. But the physics is interesting, imo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the adaptation of an organism, and might be better for a site like Biology Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well, the essence of the question seems to be why a red object would look black in low-light conditions, whereas a blue object presumably wouldn't. That seems like it might be sufficiently physics-related.

Answer (score 1):

From NOAA site: [Color Changes At Deep Depths](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/facts/red-color.html)

> As you travel from surface waters to deeper waters, the quantity of light changes; it decreases with depth. The quality of light also varies with depth. Sunlight contains all of the colors of our visible spectrum (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet). These colors combined together appear white.
>
> Red light has the longest wavelength and, therefore, the least amount of energy in the visible spectrum. Wavelength decreases and energy increases as you move from red to violet light across the spectrum in the following order: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet.
>
> As light wavelength decreases from red to blue light, so does the ability of light to penetrate water. Blue light penetrates best, green light is second, yellow light is third, followed by orange light and red light. Red light is quickly filtered from water as depth increases.
>
> All objects that are not transparent or translucent either absorb or reflect nearly all of the light that strikes them. When struck by white light (containing all colors), a red fish reflects red light and absorbs all other colors. Likewise, grass reflects green light and absorbs all other colors. White objects appear white because they reflect all colors of light in the visible spectrum. Black objects appear black because they absorb all colors of light.
>
> Now consider that red fish. If a red fish is swimming at the surface of the ocean, it appears red because it reflects red light. However, the deeper you and the fish go, the less red the fish will appear, because there is less and less red light to reflect off of the fish. At 100 meters, red light does not penetrate and, at this depth, a red fish is difficult, if not impossible to see. Instead, the fish appears blackish because there is no red light to reflect at that depth and the fish absorbs all other wavelengths of color.
>
> In the twilight zone, there are numerous animals that are black or red. At depth, these animals are not visible. The black animals absorb all colors of light available and the red animals appear black as well; there is no red light to reflect and their bodies absorb all other available wavelengths of light. Thus red and black animals predominate.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't fully understand it.
I intended to ask why red light doesn't penetrate deeply (the fish thing was just a cover).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of possibly understanding it: From [Underwater Photography](http://www.uwphotographyguide.com/underwater-photography-lighting-fundamentals)

> Water absorbs different wavelengths of light to different degrees. The longest wavelengths, with the lowest energy, are absorbed first. Red is the first to be absorbed, followed by orange & yellow. The colors disappear underwater in the same order as they appear in the color spectrum. Even water at 5ft depth will have a noticeable loss of red. For this reason, strobes are usually used to add color back to subjects.

> At what depth underwater does color disappear?

> Red - 15ft
>   orange - 25ft
>   Yellow - 35-45ft
>   Green - 70-75ft

> Don't forget to add in the horizontal distance. If you are 10ft underwater, and you are viewing an object 10ft away, the light has actually travelled 20ft, and all of the reds will be filtered out.